# TSP using divide and conquer

Tags: algorithm, traveling-salesman, divide-and-conquer

I'm solving traveling salesman problem in different ways. I've already solved it using backtracking and greedy algorithms. Now I have to solve it using divide and conquer. I understand how divide and conquer works but I can't understand how I can apply it to this problem. I tried looking for something in google but found almost nothing. I'd be vary grateful to hear some advices. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is probably, that [TSP](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/travelling-salesman-problem-set-1/) is not easily partitioned into independent sub-problems. This is a prerequisite to apply a divide and conquer strategy.

The paper [Multilevel Graph Partitioning Scheme to Solve Traveling Salesman Problem](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6209194) describes how to use multilevel graph partitioning. To reduce the overall complexity, a [K-Means](https://realpython.com/k-means-clustering-python/) clustering/partitioning algorithm is used to divide the TSP into multiple parts. In a second stage, each partition is solved separately.  As a final step, the combined solution is improved by applying the [Lin Kernighan](https://arthur.maheo.net/implementing-lin-kernighan-in-python/) heuristic.